# observe method vs Observer<>

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I was reading Android's docs having to do with LiveData and ViewModels and I was met with an entry that got me confused.

In
[LiveData Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects)
the example code implements the observer like so

```
public class NameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NameViewModel model;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Other code to setup the activity...

    // Get the ViewModel.
    model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NameViewModel.class);

    // Create the observer which updates the UI.
    final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
            // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
            nameTextView.setText(newName);
        }
    };

    // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
    model.getCurrentName().observe(this, nameObserver);
}}
```

A two step process of creating an `Observer<String>`that updates the UI, and `.observe` that observes the LiveData
whereas in [ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing) the implementation of observer is

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}


public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), { item ->
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

With a single `.observe`. I did some testing and it looks like the single `.observe` is also able to update the UI.

I also noticed that LiveData Overview was implementing the observe in an Activity and ViewModel Overview was in a fragment. Could that be the reason why the observe is implemented in a 2 step vs 1 step process?

Is one better than the other? or are they equivalent ways of writing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little practical difference between the two.  It's just a matter of syntax.

In the first example, the code is using `new Observer<String>()` to create a new instance of an object that implements the Observer interface.  This instance is passed to `observe()`.

The second example is actually doing nearly the exact same thing, except it's using [Java 8 lambda syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to collapse a lot of the code that's used to define the Observer object, and simply defining the new Observer object inline to the call to `observe()`, without even giving it a name.

Whether you use `new Observer()` or lambda syntax, the end result is basically the same - a new Observer instance is created and passed.